# Bison: $$ and $1 point to the same memory location (union YYSTYPE of two pointer types)

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I was building a parser for a very simple parser when I suddenly started getting SEGFAULTs. I've stripped down my code to the bare minimum where it goes wrong:

This is my test.flex file:

```
%{
#include "test.tab.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
model { yylval.a = new double(); return IDENTIFIER; }
.     { cerr << "Unrecognized token!" << endl; exit(1); }
%%
```

This is my test.y file:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int yylex();
int yyerror(const char *p) { cerr << "Error" << endl; }
%}

%union YYSTYPE {
  double* a;
  int* b;
};

%token <a> IDENTIFIER 
%type <b> expression

%%
expression : IDENTIFIER { cout << "got here! " << $1 << "|" << $$ << endl; };
%%

int main()
{
  yyparse();
  cout << "Success!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Our union consists of two pointers, a and b. $1 and $$ are of different types (a and b respectively).

On input "model", the output is "got here! 0x372a28|0x372a28" (and "Success!" on a second line), which means that $1 and $$ point to the same memory location! This of course causes all kinds of bad things to happen.

The assignment to yylval.a in the lexer is needed for the bug to manifest.

I use Bison 2.4.1 and Flex 2.5.4, both for Windows (using GnuWin32). Am I doing something wrong? Is this a (known) bug?

EDIT:
If I change the union to:

```
%union YYSTYPE {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

and the rule to

```
expression : IDENTIFIER { cout << "got here! " << &$1 << "|" << &$$ << endl; };
```

(and remove the assignment in the lexer) the resulting memory locations described *are* different, which leads me to believe the memory locations of the variables themselves are different if no pointers are used. However, if this were the case if I use pointers, the assignment "yylval.a = new double();" should only change $1 and leave $$ untouched.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in Bison, that's how Bison works. It uses a stack to process the intermediate parsing results, and in your rule there's one token to be shifted out from the stack and one to be added, so the item to be popped out and the item to be pushed in obviously reside in the same memory location.

Because you are doing type coercion here (?), I guess what you should have in the action is something like

```
double *a = $1;
$$ = new int((int)(*a));
delete a;
```

Note that once you write to $$ you can't read $1 anymore because you have now taken the stack slot where $1 used to be.

Comment: If I change the union to YYSTYPE { int a; int b; }, the print statement to &$1 << "|" << &$$, and comment out the assignment in my .flex file, the resulting memory locations *are* different. I could be wrong, but I don't think that's consistent with your explanation.

Comment: Also, the code generated is "(yyvsp[(1) - (1)].a) << "|" << (yyval.b)" - again, I could be wrong, but I don't see a stack here.

Comment: The array `yyvsp` is the stack. The stack holds the results of processing the rule. Here, it's the same object as went into the rule. Your rule does nothing but accept its input as its output, so the output and input are the very same object.

Comment: Printing $1, $$, &$1 and &$$ gives me "0x342a30|0x342a30|0x28fa00|0x28feac", so $1 and $$ are two different variables, but they point to the same object. In other words, I still don't get it, but I'll see if I can work around it and get my code to work. Thanks for your attempt to enlighten me.

Comment: They are two different variables, yes, but they point to the same element in the parser stack. The only thing you need to "get" is that (1) you need to write something to $$ in almost every rule, and (2) once you write to $$, you can't read the values behind $1, $2 and so on, i.e. the write to $$ should be the last thing that happens in your action block.

Comment: @David the output is typed as int* whereas the input is typed as double* so it's just not a pass-through rule.

Comment: @antti.huima: He told it the output is an int* and the input is a double*, but never did any actual conversion. Basically, he lied to it, so it lied back to him.

Answer (score 0):

The expression has only one component, so its left side and right side are precisely the same. I'm not sure why you find this surprising.

I think I may know where your confusion lies:

```
expression : IDENTIFIER
```

This says that one valid form for an `expression` is an `IDENTIFIER`. Thus anything that's a valid `IDENTIFIER` is also a valid `expression`.

Comment: My surprise lies in the fact that the system with the $n and $$ signs for the values of (non)terminals and the resulting value seems to use overlapping memory locations in my case. I know that an IDENTIFIER can be reduced to an expression.

Comment: Your rule just says, "if the input is an IDENTIFIER, accept it as an expression". It does no processing of any kind, so the output is precisely the same object as the input. If you want to create a new object of some other kind as the expression and assign it some value associated with the IDENTIFIER, you can (see antti.huima's answer). But it won't happen by itself.